# Как загружать данные постепенно? Firebase android java

Tags: java, android, запрос, firebase-database

В данные момент у меня грузится с базы все данные , я же хочу чтобы она грузилась с определенным количеством и достижении конца , догружалась дальше.

```
private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter getMAdapter(Query query){

    mActivity = getActivity();
    final Dialog mDialog = new Dialog(mActivity, R.style.NewDialog);
    mDialog.addContentView(
            new ProgressBar(mActivity),
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    );
    mDialog.setCancelable(true);
    mDialog.show();

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Post> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Post>()
            .setQuery(query, Post.class)
            .build();

    mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(PostViewHolder viewHolder, int position, final Post model) {
            final DatabaseReference postRef = getRef(position);

            // Determine if the current user has liked this post and set UI accordingly
            if (model.stars.containsKey(getUid())) {
                viewHolder.starView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_toggle_star_24);
            } else {
                viewHolder.starView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_toggle_star_outline_24);
            }

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(model.kzSongytblink))
                viewHolder.mImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.on_line_logo);
            else viewHolder.mImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.off_line_logo);

            // Bind Post to ViewHolder, setting OnClickListener for the star button
            viewHolder.bindToPost(model, new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View starView) {
                    // Need to write to both places the post is stored
                    DatabaseReference globalPostRef = mDatabase.child("songsDB").child(postRef.getKey());
                    // Run two transactions
                    onStarClicked(globalPostRef);
                }
            });

            viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, PostDetailActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(PostDetailActivity.EXTRA_POST_KEY, postRef.getKey());
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public PostViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());
            return new PostViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_post, viewGroup, false));
        }

        @Override
        public void onDataChanged() {
            super.onDataChanged();
            mDialog.dismiss();
        }
    };
    return mAdapter;
}


public void ShowData(Query postsQuery) {
    mAdapter = getMAdapter(postsQuery);
    mRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);

}
```

Comment: Где в показанном коде у тебя идет чтение и что не получается? Для insert бывает batchSize, для select ты можешь сделать временный пул. От чего зависеть будет тот "конец" которого ты хочешь достигать?

Comment: к примеру , для начала пусть загрузиться до 30 элемента в списке. Когда пользователь дойдет до 30 элемента он должен грузить дальше следующие 30 элементов .

Comment: Покажите ваши наработки и, что у вас не получается. Идея есть, а ошибки в коде?

Comment: https://proandroiddev.com/firebase-database-paging-android-f59e6dd0dc75